# How to avoid duplicates in Listbox Arraylist?

Tags: c#, arraylist

```
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "";

    if (listboxl.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listboxl.Items.Count; i++)
        {
                if (listboxl.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    if (!arraylist1.Contains(listboxl.Items[i]))
                    {
                        arraylist1.Add(listboxl.Items[i]);

                    }
                    //else if (listboxl.Items.Contains(listboxr.Items[i]))
                    //{
                    //    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Unit Already added !')", true);
                    //}
                }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.Count; i++)
        {
             if (!listboxr.Items.Contains(((ListItem)arraylist1[i])))
            {
                listboxr.Items.Add(((ListItem)arraylist1[i]));

            }

             listboxl.Items.Remove(((ListItem)arraylist1[i])); 
        }

        listboxr.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }     
}
```

I am using this code to add items to the list, but it allows duplicate values. Kindly help me out.

Comment: what items are in `listbox1`? You should be better off using `List<T>` rather than `ArrayList`

Comment: Without knowing what items are in your `ListBox` it's hard to say for sure. At the moment you're comparing an object, but my bet would be your items are primitive data types, say a `string` or `int`, in which case you need to cast the item to such before running the comparison. Eg., for a `string`, `castItem = listbox1.Items[I].ToString();`

Comment: Items used are string in listboxl.. I have two listboxes in which one gets populated by the values it has, another is the above listboxl.. If i move already existing values it must not allow !